# Computing factorials modulo p^N

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can one compute $(p-1)!$ modulo $p^2$ in time polynomial in $\log p$?  I can do it modulo $p$!  (The last one is an exclamation point, not a factorial.)

More generally, I would like to be able to compute $d!$ modulo $p^N$ in time polynomial in $N \log p$.

Comment: How do you compute $(p-1)!$ modulo $p$ in time $\log p$?

Comment: For $(p-1)!$ modulo $p$: Wilson's theorem and Primes is in P?

Comment: [May be relevant](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~qcheng/paper/factorial.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

I believe that the question whether $(p-1)! \bmod p^2$ is computable in polynomial time is still open. The best I am aware of is $O(p^{1/2+\epsilon})$, but I am not a specialist on this issue.

The computation of $(p-1)! \bmod p^2$ plays a role in certain p-adic algorithms to compute zeta functions of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$. 
There is an algorithm of David Harvey for zeta functions of hypersurfaces, where your question plays a role. I.e., the fact that this is not known that  $(p-1)! \bmod p^2$ can be computed in less than $O(p^{1/2+\epsilon})$ is an obstruction to improve the complexity of this algorithm. (See the slides "Computing zeta functions of projective surfaces in large characteristic" on http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~harvey/.)

Answer (score 5):

As you may know, a Wilson prime is a prime $p$ such that $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{p^2}$. Only three are known (5, 13, and 563), despite searches going up to $5\times10^8$. Presumably, the people doing these searches have looked into your question, so maybe it's a good idea to go through the literature on Wilson primes. The Wikipedia article will get you started.

Comment: Regarding the search for Wilson primes, I have the impression that the distributed search in http://www.ibercivis.net/ is currently at around $2\times10^9$. I don't know much about the subject, but I would start by reading *Crandall, Dilcher and Pomerance: A search for Wieferich and Wilson primes*, http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-217/S0025-5718-97-00791-6/S0025-5718-97-00791-6.pdf.